# Flume failing for xls file

Tags: hadoop, flume

Flume is failing while we are inserting xls or xlsx file in the spool directory.

Uncaught exception in SpoolDirectorySource thread. Restart or reconfigure Flume to continue processing.
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
        at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)

Comment: It's hard to say without your Flume config, but you should be aware that Flume can't magically detect and handle Excel files. You need to convert them to CSV beforehand, or write a custom Flume source.

Comment: @BenWatson Thank you for your inputs, is it only for xls files, was actually testing its capability to do a blind copy from local to hdfs irrespective of the file format

Comment: Please can you add your Flume config to the question. It's impossible for anyone to help you without knowing what you're doing.